# How to calculate the phases after a pitch shift on the STFT?

Tags: python, audio, pytorch, spectrogram, pitch-shifting

I use `torch.stft()` to generate a spectrogram.
I want to perform a pitch shift on the audio.
The end result should be an STFT of the pitch-shifted audio.

I can't `phase_vocoder` -> `istft` -> `resample` -> `stft` because that's too slow.

Instead, I wrote some code that makes a new spectrogram, where the `n`th frequency bin is just the `n * scaling_factor`th frequency bin of the original spectrogram, interpolated for fractional indices:

```py
def interpolate(frequencies: torch.Tensor, sgram: torch.Tensor):
    start = frequencies.int()
    frac = (frequencies - start)[:, None]
    return sgram[start, :] * (1 - frac) + sgram[start + 1, :] * frac

def pitch_shift_spectrogram(sgram: torch.Tensor, semitones: torch.Tensor):
    scaling_factor = 2 ** (-semitones / 12)
    frequencies = torch.arange(0, sgram.shape[0], 1, device=sgram.device)
    shifted_frequencies = frequencies * scaling_factor
    shifted_mags = interpolate(shifted_frequencies, sgram.abs())
    phases = sgram.angle() # ??? what do i do? help
    return torch.polar(shifted_mags, phases)
```

I tested it on [this sound file](https://www2.cs.uic.edu/%7Ei101/SoundFiles/CantinaBand3.wav).

The spectrogram (magnitude only) that this generates is good enough; stealing the phases from a complete, working pitch shift implementation makes it sound fine:

```py
import torch
import torchaudio
import IPython.display as display

waveform, sample_rate = torchaudio.load("CantinaBand3.wav")
waveform = waveform[0]

shifted_waveform = torchaudio.functional.pitch_shift(waveform, sample_rate, 2)
working_sgram = torch.stft(shifted_waveform, 1024, return_complex=True)

unshifted_sgram = torch.stft(waveform, 1024, return_complex=True)
broken_sgram = pitch_shift_spectrogram(unshifted_sgram, torch.tensor(2))

broken_sgram = torch.polar(broken_sgram.abs(), working_sgram.angle())
display.display(display.Audio(torch.istft(broken_sgram, 1024), rate=sample_rate))
```

Is it possible to calculate the phase information of the pitch-shifted signal through the STFT alone? Does PyTorch offer any built-in functions that do this for me?
Also, one of the model parameters affects the `semitones` parameter in the pitch shift function. With the interpolation, will autograd backprop through that fine?